# Get the location of environment variable when trying ret2libc exploit

Tags: linux, gdb, exploit

Recently I'm learning some experiment about ret2libc exploit, I found that we can using the environment variable to store payload, and the following code `getenv.c` can help us to get the location of the environment variable:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


    char *ptr;
    if(argc < 3) {
            printf("Usage: %s <environment var> <target program>\n", argv[0]);
            exit(0);
    }

    ptr = getenv(argv[1]); /* Get env var location. */
    ptr += (strlen(argv[0]) - strlen(argv[2])); /* Adjust for program name. */
    printf("%s will be at %p\n", argv[1], ptr);

}
```

we can use the program this way:

`$ ~/getenv FAV ./program
FAV will be at 0xbfffff22`

It makes me so confused that the `ptr` value is not used directly, but do the adujstment `(strlen(argv[0]) - strlen(argv[2]))`; Why?

Answer (score 0):

The environment variable address on program `foo` is guessed when using your `getenv` binary.

The program name comes before the environment variables and so, if the original program's name is longer or shorter, it will change the environment variables addresses.

This is why you substract the `getenv` program name length to the env address, and add the `foo` binary name length instead.